# Why am I getting the KeyError: 'CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET' from the default python-docs-samples/appengine/flexible/storage example

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am attempting to use Google Cloud Storage with Google App Engine and am currently looking at the “[Using Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage)” documentation page.  It references the “[Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart) for Python in the App Engine Flexible Environment” project. I have pulled the “python-docs-samples/appengine/flexible/storage” from the Github and have followed the instructions regarding the virtualenv listed in the Quickstart.

When I run `python main.py` it results in and error:

```
File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
    CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET = os.environ['CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET']
  File [PATH_TO_FILE]/python-docs-samples/appengine/flexible/storage/env/bin/../lib/python2.7/Use
rDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET'
```

I did provide the name of my bucket in the app.yml file

```
#[START env]
env_variables:
  CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: jcolumbetestbucket
#[END env]
```

Some areas of confusion I have:

Both the "Quickstart" and "Using Cloud Storage" projects it seems to want to use python 3, as listed in the app.yml files, but when I run the vurtualenv commands, it installs python2.7. I did do an install for python 3 via `sudo pip3 install virtualenv` and and run both `python3 main.py` and `python main.py` and still get the error.

Also this particular documentation says to use the `python main.py` command to run the local dev server, while others I have been looking at for the last few days says to use `dev_appserver.py .` command.

Any insight or help would be helpful, as I have been trying to get this to work for days.

Comment: is the issue solved now?

Answer (score 0):

There are two different environments you can build your application in: Standard and Flexible. For more on that see [Choosing an App Engine Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments).

`dev_appserver.py` is a sandbox used for testing apps meant for the Standard environment which loads environment variables from `app.yaml` without a problem.

The example you are using is meant for the Flexible environment. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/testing-and-deploying-your-app) there are multiple ways of running these but none of them seem to be able to load environment variables locally.

You have two options: either stick with the Standard environment if it meets your needs or hardcode your environment variables for testing purposes.